# Cannot populate listbox with data from azure

Tags: c#, windows, azure, casting, azure-mobile-services

I pulled data from azure mobile service, but when I populate the data to a longlistselector, it throws a nullreference exception.

```
private MobileServiceCollection<users, users> items;
private IMobileServiceTable<users> user =
        App.MobileService.GetTable<users>();
 items = await user
            .Where(users => users.age == 20).ToCollectionAsync();
foreach (users usr in items.Cast<users>())
        {
            listui.ItemsSource.Add(usr.age);
        }
listui.ItemsSource.Add(items.Cast<users>());
```

i even tried to populate the longlistselector directly passing the items object without cast, but it just gives "users.age" as the items. however the number of items are correct.

```
listui.ItemsSource = items
```

XAML

```
 <phone:LongListSelector x:Name="listui" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="151" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="363" Margin="52,386,0,0" Background="#FF787878"/>
```

Help !

Comment: No, windows phone 8.1

Comment: could you post your XAML for the list box?

Comment: yeah done, btw sorry its a longlistselector not listbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the DataTemplate and Binding, Try this,

```
<phone:LongListSelector Name="listui" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" LayoutMode="List" IsGroupingEnabled="False" Width="446">
<phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
<StackPanel>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding age}" />
</StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
</phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
</phone:LongListSelector>
```

Comment: works !!, thanks Sajeetharan, greatly appreciated ! :)